# Is the given language DCFL?

Tags: context-free, finite-automata, nondeterminism

$a^ib^jc^k | (i = j)$ then k is even?

I can write it as
$a^ib^ic^k$ where k is even

OR

$a^ib^jc^k where (i != j)$

Both are DCFL and union of DCFL may be DCFL, but I think because of OR operator it gives a sense of parallelism and hence NCFL.

I haven't tried to make a DPDA for it, because in exam I might not be have much time to draw.

I don't think it is DCFL.

**Theoretically, is this approach right ?**

Comment: I think there will will be two copies of same machine running parallely .

Comment: I am getting 3 states . is that right ? So, it means this language is DCFL.

Comment: Try 2 states. Anyway I do not know if it is enough, maybe the pumping lemma for DCFL would be nice to prove it beyond doubt? Or converting DPDA to DCFL?

Comment: pumping lemma will only conclude that it is not regular . Anyways, still i am stuck at 3 states. How you got 2 ?

Comment: I will disagree on that: [The pumping lemma for CFL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages), also we have questions about it here (search works fine, I have checked it). I did 2 states because I am too lazy to make 3. It would be nice to make DCFL and Pumping lemma, maybe even answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a DPDA for your language as follows. When reading $a$s, the machine pushes $A$s onto the stack. When reading $b$s, the machine pops them, noting to itself if there are more $b$s than $a$s. When it reads the first $c$, it can use the top-of-stack to tell if the number of $a$ was equal to the number of $b$s; if so, it transfers control to a DFA for $(cc)^*$, and otherwise it transfers control to a DFA for $c^*$.